# Upload file to WWW directory from WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, web, file-upload, public-html

I am trying to upload a PHP file to WordPress root folder (www or public_html).

How can I do it ?

I want to implement it on my theme. I tried with `move_uploaded_file` , but it's not uploading anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code after require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-settings.php'); declaration.

```
define('UPLOADS', 'files');
```

Please note that, you have to use the default wordpress media manager instead of your own custom code with "move_uploaded_file".

Please refer, http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-upload-dir/

Answer (score -1):

Just use ftp, that's the only easiest way to upload files to your root directory with wordpress.
I guess your using webhosting for your wordpress website, login on their website and check for ftp credentials or just ask them for it.
Most of the time i use filezilla for uploading files to wordpress. [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)

Comment: i am asking can i do via theme coding  ? why normal php upload script not working with wordpress ? i can do with FTP too , but this time i have to upload file wordpress root .. but i only have WPadmin account ..